# Jackson ObjectMapper default values with lombok on codhaus and fasterexml

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

I was using `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper` to deserialize a JSON string with default values as follows:

I have the following POJO:

```
@Data
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CompanyRequest {
    @Builder.Default
    private String email = "";
    private int company;
    @Builder.Default
    List<UserIdMapping> users = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and when executing the following:

```
CompanyRequest companyRequest = objectMapper.readValue(message, CompanyRequest.class);
```

where message is:

```
{
  "email": "john@doe.com",
  "company": 42,
}
```

it worked as expected, meaning `companyRequest` initialized with `users` as empty `ArrayList`.

then I switched to `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`, but `users` for the same `message` was `null`.

I was able to solve it with the following changes:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Builder
public class CompanyRequest {
    private String email;
    private int company;
    private List<UserIdMapping> users;

    @JsonCreator
    public CompanyRequest() {
        this.email = "";
        this.users = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Builder
    public CompanyRequest(String email, int company, List<UserIdMapping> users) {
        this.sfAccountId = StringUtils.isEmpty(email) ? "" : email;
        this.company = company;
        this.users = CollectionUtils.isEmpty(users) ? new ArrayList<>() : users;
    }
}
```

but after knowing that `codehaus` is actually working as intended without this manipulation I was wondering is there a cleaner way to do it with `fasterxml`, since `fasterxml` is the newer version of `ObjectMapper`,
meaning is it a feature that enables it?

Comment: How `fasterxml jackson` behaves if you remove `@Builder.Default` from `users`?

Comment: it still sets `users` as `null` this is because jackson faterxml uses the `@AllArgsConstructor` which sets `users` as `null`, while codhaus uses default constructor and setters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "codehaus" version of Jackson is the 1.x version of Jackson. Since 2.0, Jackson is located at "com.fasterxml.jackson". Without having tested it, it is very likely that the behavior simply (and intentionally) changed with Jackson 2.

However, as you found out by yourself, you can explicitly advise Jackson to use the no-args constructor when deserializing. You can also put that annotation on a lombok-generated constructor, so you do not have to write it manually:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = @JsonCreator)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CompanyRequest {
    @Builder.Default
    private String email = "";
    private int company;
    @Builder.Default
    List<UserIdMapping> users = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Make sure you use at least Lombok v1.18.2 so ensure the `@Builder.Default` values are also set within this constructor.

Consider putting `@Jacksonized @Builder` on the class if you want immutability and the builder to be the only way of creating instances (with at least Lombok v1.18.16):

```java
@Jacksonized
@Builder
@Value
public class CompanyRequest {
    @Builder.Default
    private String email = "";
    private int company;
    @Singular
    List<UserIdMapping> users;
}
```

Comment: thank you! looks exactly what I was looking for, testing it now

Comment: Did you get it to work, or are there still problems?

Answer (score 0):

Use the @Jacksonized annotation provided by lombok